Convert imported text to date using Excel vba
I am trying to automate a process that takes a 89-column text file using "^" as a delimiter, importing it into a CSV file, loading the csv file into Access to generate two reports. The text file comes from another agency, so I have no say in how the file is formatted. In the text file there are 6 columns of dates. Two of the six are formatted as mmddyyyy for DOB and DOS. The remaining are formatted as mm/dd/yyyy. I am trying to reformat the DOB and DOS columns to mm/dd/yyyy so the CVS file can be imported into Access. I have tried NumberFormat using both the CELLS and RANGE references without success. I cannot supply actual data due to HIPPA laws. Any assistance would be appreciated.
       With wkSheet.UsedRange.Columns("L", "BZ").Cells
            .TextToColumns Destination:=.Cells(2), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, FieldInfo:=Array(1, xlMDYFormat)
           .NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
        End With

With wkSheet
.Range ("L2:L50000").NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
.Range ("BZ2:BZ5000").NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
End With

This is the code for the text import:
        strAscensionFile = "L:\& strXReportDate & "_FCC_FHC_MCW_PB.txt"
    Open strFile For Input As #2
    While Not EOF(2)
        Line Input #2, strLineText
        strLineValueArray() = Split(strLineText, "^")
        For intColNum = 1 To 89
            wkSheet.Cells(intRowNum, intColNum).Value = strLineValueArray(intColNum - 1)
        Next intColNum
        intRowNum = intRowNum + 1
    Wend
    Close #2


"L", "BZ" is not a valid reference for Columns. L2:L50000 and BZ2:BZ5000 need to be enclosed in ".

BigBen - I did use that format. I was trying to recall code from memory. It still did not work.

Please edit your question to include the correct code, otherwise we will be debugging the wrong problem(s)

Please also include a representative data sample. There is no need to use confidential data. Just make up some data that demonstrates the problem clearly, and also show your actual code, not what you think you wrote.
